# How to pass parameter variable from Django web to python script?

Tags: python, django

I have a python script that will be triggered to read an inbox and send email to an gmail account when some condition is meet. In order to send , the script will filter through subject or text of the incoming email. Currently the script is just hard-coded format and I prefer the condition is dynamically set by the user. I created a django website and let user to input their condition, but I do not know how can I pass the parameter from the web to my python script. I already do my researched on the internet but couldn't found any useful source, does anyone can help me or send my any related article for me to read ? Thanks

My py script

```
import datetime
import email
import imaplib
import mailbox
import smtplib

EMAIL_ACCOUNT = "xxx@gmail.com"
PASSWORD = "xxx"

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)
mail.list()
mail.select('inbox')
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "UNSEEN") # (ALL/UNSEEN)
i = len(data[0].split())

for x in range(i):
    latest_email_uid = data[0].split()[x]
    result, email_data = mail.uid('fetch', latest_email_uid, '(RFC822)')
    # result, email_data = conn.store(num,'-FLAGS','\\Seen')
    # this might work to set flag to seen, if it doesn't already
    raw_email = email_data[0][1]
    raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
    email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

    # Header Details
    date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(email_message['Date'])
    if date_tuple:
        local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
        local_message_date = "%s" %(str(local_date.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")))
    email_from = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['From'])))
    email_to = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['To'])))
    subject = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['Subject'])))

    # Body details
    for part in email_message.walk():

        if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
            body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            print("From:", email_from)

            print("Email To:", email_to)
            print("date:", local_message_date)
            print("Subject:", subject)
            print("body:", body.decode('utf-8'))

            '''If subject have test it will send specific email to recipient'''
            if "Consent"  in subject:
                server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                server.starttls()
                server.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, PASSWORD)

                msg = "ALERT NOTICE!"
                server.sendmail(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, "xxx@gmail.com", msg)
                server.quit()
            else:
                print( "no email");

        else:
            continue
```

My django web currently is just html form
[My django web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqNae.png)

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,500" rel="stylesheet">

<style>

body {font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;}
.button {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color:  #ff9633;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left:500px;
}

.button span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button span:after {
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.button:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.button:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 45%;

  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #ff9633;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #ff9633;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ff9633;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color:
#fa7d34;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>

  <li><div id="myBtn1"><a href="#AddCon">Alert Policies</a></div></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Test3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Test4</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Alert Policies</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <p style="font-size:14px">Please select an event parameter as well as the condition type and value that apply.</p>

        <!-- parameter drop down -->
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <label for="Parameter"> <b style="font-size:13px" >  Event parameter to evaluate </b></label>
            <select name="Parameter" id="Parameter" style="width:340px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;">
                <option disabled selected value>select a parameter</option>
                <option value="Subject">Subject</option>
                <option value="Text">Text</option>

            </select>
            <br><br>

            <label for="Condition">   <b style="font-size:13px" >  Type of condition </b></label>
            <select name="Condition" id="Condition" style="width:340px; margin-left:69px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;">
                <option disabled selected value>select a condition</option>
                <option value="Equals">Equals</option>
                <option value="Contain">Contain</option>
                <option value="NotContain">Does not contain</option>

            </select>
            <br><br>

            <label for="valuetomatch"> <b style="font-size:13px" > Value to match</b></label>
            <input type="text" id="valuetomatch" name="valuetomatch" style="width:333px; margin-left:80px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;">
            <br>
            <br>
<button class="button"><span>OK</span></button>

  </form>

    </div>


  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please share the codes regarding `I created a django website and let user to input their condition`?

Comment: I just created the html form, its just front end. I do not know how to make it pass parameter. I updated my html form above. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your condition data is serializable, then you can use [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) to run python script. It'll be as simple as:

```py
# in your Django code that run on user submitting data
...
send_email.delay()
...

# Celery task
@shared_task(bind=True)
def send_email(list_of_your_condition_parameters):
    # do job
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this to see if it work or not